# Why Telegram keyboard not send with Guzzle request

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, guzzle

```php
$params = [
    'chat_id' => $this->chatID,
    'text' => 'What?',
    'reply_markup' => [
        'resize_keyboard' => true,
        'keyboard' => [
            [
                ['text' => 'text1'],
                ['text' => 'text2'],
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$this->client->request('POST', $this->apiUrl . '/sendMessage', array('query' => $params));
```

The message works! But the keboards doesn't show.

Comment: Are you urlencoding all the chars?

Comment: Hmm, guzzle http client, use urlencoding?

Comment: please, whan you ask a question about a lib or a package that is used with different programming language specify in the text and/or in the tags what language are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that Guzzle does not urlencode any deep query params, I've managed to send the keyboard by using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the keyboard, before sending to Guzzle;

```php
<?php

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    CONST CHAT_ID = '~~';
    CONST TOKEN   = '~~';
    CONST BASE    = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN;

    $client = new Client();
    $client->request('POST', BASE . '/sendMessage', [
        'query' => [
            'chat_id' => CHAT_ID,
            'text' => 'Hi Maxim!',
            'reply_markup' => json_encode([
                "inline_keyboard" => [
                    [
                        [
                            "text" => "Yes",
                            "callback_data" => "yes"
                        ],
                        [
                            "text" => "No",
                            "callback_data" => "no"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ])
        ]
    ]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, need json_encode for reply markup