# How to pass an object into the http client request?

Tags: php, symfony4, symfony-http-client

I have tried making a HTTP request using `CURL` as below:

```
$rawQuery = '{
    "CUSTNAME" : "1970188",
    "CURDATE":"2020-12-28T00:00:00+02:00",
    "BOOKNUM":"Test BookNum",
    "DETAILS":"Test Details"
}';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://somelink.co.de");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rawQuery); 
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
```

This one is returning me result. But when I try to implement the same using Symfony HTTP Client, I am getting 400 error.

This is the code, I have tried.

```
$response = $this->client->request('POST', $url, [
    'auth_basic' => [
        'username',
        'password'
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json', 
    ],
    'json' => $rawQuery
]);
```

I am not sure what I am missing in `Client`

Can anybody please help me ?

Comment: Try using `url_encode` on the JSON object. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200037/why-telegram-keyboard-not-send-with-guzzle-request/66243205#66243205) had a similar issue using the `request`

Comment: yes I have already tried `'json' => json_encode($rawQuery)` This results me 500 error

Comment: Are you sure this needs to go under `'json'` key? Shouldn't that be `'body'`?

Comment: @El_Vanja I have tried body, query & json. Latest I tried is 'body' => json_decode($rawQuery, true)

Comment: This isn't valid JSON in your question. You should remove the trailing comma at the end. Is this present in actual code? If so, that may well be the source of your problem.

Comment: @El_Vanja I have updated the `$rawQuery` from my question.

Comment: Then I'll take it that it was only an error in the question. Outside of that and using `'body' => $rawQuery`, I have no more ideas. If you take a look at Symfony's [CurlHttpClient implementation](https://github.com/symfony/http-client/blob/5.x/CurlHttpClient.php#L260), they take the body (as a string) and set it to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` just like you do. Do you get anything else as a response (a message specifying what went wrong) or just the status code?

Comment: I couldn't find any error message. So I test only with `$response->getStatusCode()`

Comment: `getContent()` gives nothing?

Comment: HTTP/2 500 returned for ...

Answer (score 0):

Your Raw query is incorrect..  This should be a php array, Symfony is trying to json_encode() this for you when you use the 'json' key in the request.  Reformat your $rawQuery to be

```
$rawQuery = [
    "CUSTNAME" => "1970188",
    "CURDATE"  => "2020-12-28T00:00:00+02:00",
    "BOOKNUM"  => "Test BookNum",
    "DETAILS"  => "Test Details"
];
```

Comment: I have tried changing the query. And used `'json' => json_encode($rawQuery)`

Comment: @nas That would make no difference, it would be just the same as in your question. What you'd be doing there is specifying an array and manually encoding it into a JSON string, which would in turn get double encoded. `'json' => $rawQuery` with the raw query defined as an array is what Ryan is suggesting here.

Comment: ya @nas the framework will auto encode it when you use the 'json' array key.  if you REALLY want to keep the $rawQuery the way it is then you would need to `'json' => json_decode($rawQuery, true)` which is a little strange.

Answer (score 0):

The $rawQuery variable contains a JSON-formatted string representing the data to be sent in the request body.

`curl_init()` initializes a new cURL session.

`curl_setopt()` is used to set various options for the cURL transfer. Here are the options being set:

`CURLOPT_URL:` The URL to which the request will be sent (https://somelink.co.de in this case).

`CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH:` The HTTP authentication method to be used. It's set to `CURLAUTH_BASIC`, indicating basic authentication.

`CURLOPT_USERPWD:` The username and password for basic authentication in the format "username:password".

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER:` Setting this option to 1 tells cURL to return the transfer as a string instead of outputting it directly.

`CURLOPT_POST:` Set to 1 to specify that we want to perform an HTTP POST request.

`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER:` An array of HTTP header fields to be included in the request. In this case, it specifies that the request body is in JSON format.

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS:` The data to be sent as the request body. In this case, it's the JSON data from the $rawQuery variable.

`curl_exec($ch)` executes the cURL session and performs the HTTP POST request. The response from the server is stored in the $curl_response variable.

After this code executes, the variable $curl_response will contain the response received from the server as a string. Depending on the API or server response, the contents of $curl_response will vary. It's important to handle the response accordingly, such as checking for errors or processing the data sent back by the server.

Additionally, you may want to include error handling and exception management in your code to handle situations where the cURL request fails or the response is not as expected.